# Entendendo o survey

Tags: banco-de-dados, r

Vamos lá...

Estou estudando o pacote survey

Comecei estudando esta página

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/svy_r_scpsu.htm

mas as minhas perguntas são mais básicas

Eu tenho já carregado a seguinte base de dados

```
> mydata
  id str clu     wt hou85 ue91 lab91
1  1   2   1  0.500 26881 4123 33786
2  2   2   1  0.500 26881 4123 33786
3  3   1  10  1.004  9230 1623 13727
4  4   1   4  1.893  4896  760  5919
5  5   1   7  2.173  4264  767  5823
6  6   1  32  2.971  3119  568  4011
7  7   1  26  4.762  1946  331  2543
8  8   1  18  6.335  1463  187  1448
9  9   1  13 13.730   675  129   927
>
```

Gostaria de entender muito bem o que está se fazendo no seguinte código

```
mydesign <- 
svydesign(
    id = ~clu ,
    data = mydata ,
    weight = ~wt ,
    strata = ~str
)
```

Qual é o papel do argumento id = ~clu?

E qual é o papel do argumento strata= ~str ?

Pelo pouco que eu li, parece que acontece algum tipo de divisão ou separação do arquivo mydata. Mas não consigo visualizar isso...

Agora observem na seguinte sequencia de comandos

```
> summary(mydata$ue91)
    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
     129     331     760    1401    1623    4123 
>
> options(survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")
> svymean(~ue91, mydesign)
       mean     SE
ue91 445.18 185.56
```

Primeiro a media é 1401 e depois a media é 445.18. Por que?

O que significa SE?

Bom galera, por agora minhas dúvidas são essas

Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O pacote `survey` serve para análise de amostras complexas. Isso é: onde nem todos elementos tem a mesma probabilidade de serem amostrados, e é nisso que entra os parâmetros `strata`. `weight` e `id` entram.

Nesse teu banco fica complicado explicar o que é o que, pois não entendi direito ele, mas vou tentar te explicar pelo banco da amostra do IBGE. A amostra funciona da seguinte maneira: São amostrados 5% dos domicílios (esse valor pode mudar de uma cidade para outra), onde todos os moradores desses domicílios respondem o questionário amostral, que é mais completo que o do universo. Em seguida, esses domicilios são reunidos em AEDs (Areas de Expansão de Dados da Amostra). Os dados (disponíveis [aqui](ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Censos/Censo_Demografico_2010/Resultados_Gerais_da_Amostra/Microdados/)) apresentam, entre muitas, as seguintes variáveis:

```
V0010 - Peso amostral
V0011 - AED
V0300 - Controle
```

A variável `V00100 - Peso amostral` é calculada após a realização da amostra e do censo, através de variáveis em comum com o questionário amostral e do universo. Usando o `survey`, devemos declarar os seguintes parâmetros:

```
 svydesign(ids = ~ V0300,  strata = ~ V0011, weights = ~ V0010, data = dados)
```

No caso, o parâmetro `ids` recebe a variável `V0300`, pois ela é o código da casa amostrada, e todos os integrantes da casa são entrevistados (portanto, a casa é um cluster, e não um estrato). Já os estratos são as AEDs (`V0011`), porque somente um percentual da sua população (de residências) foi amostrada. O peso amostral (`weights`) recebe `V0010`.

A diferença nos resultados que tu obteve é porque o 2o é uma média ponderada, usando como peso a variável `wt`. Da para obter o mesmo valor através do comando:

```
with(mydata, sum((wt * ue91)/sum(wt)))
[1] 445.1821
```

Já SE, é o erro padrão da estimativa da média.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta... deu para entender um pouco... E no caso de svytotal(~ue91, mydesign)? O que isso significa? Qual seria um caminho alternativo para chegar a esse mesmo resultado sem usar as funções do pacote survey? tipo aquela que você deu: with(mydata, sum((wt * ue91)/sum(wt)))

Comment: O `svytotal()` é para estimar a soma da variável. No caso, um `with(mydata, sum(wt * ue91))` deve retornar o mesmo valor (Note que não to mais dividindo pela soma de `wt`).